# QGIS Cloud - Adding User Alternatives

Tags: qgis-cloud

I'm having trouble adding users to a map in QGIS Cloud Pro. Is there any alternative way anyone knows of to add users to a map other than using the 'edit Map' form?

The 'edit Map' form seems very unresponsive trying to add users from what appears to be a drop-down list of all users on the platform. I just can't add anyone. After typing in a letter into the 'select a user to add' box, the web page just hangs.

Comment: Question still applies re: alternative ways to add users to a map, but I've tried using Edge (rather than Chrome) and the drop down eventually loads at least.

Comment: Please contact support@qgiscloud.com for further help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/118001)